# Factor of 1/2 in RMS Voltage

Tags: thevenin, rms

Given the following circuit, I would like to calculate the Thevenin equivalent of the voltage in RMS.

I know that R = 400 [Ω]; e(t) = 40 cos(10^4 t) [V].

However, I can't understand why there is a factor of 1/2:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There was an image of R/(R+R) divider =1/2

Comment: If you assume the resistor values are the same, then you're doing a voltage divider, hence the 1/2

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks a lot! I'm new in circuits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a voltage divider.

\$V_{eq} = (e(t)_{RMS}R_2)/(R_1+R_2)\$... but if \$R_1 = R_2\$, then \$V_{eq} = e(t)_{RMS}/2 \$